# Using dynamic values in controls

Tags: manipulate

The following code displays a plot and tries to display the `x=1` value of the same plot in the control area:

```
DynamicModule[{lbl}, 
 Manipulate[lbl = ToString[Sin[x (1 + a x)] /. x -> 1]; 
  Labeled[Plot[Sin[x (1 + a x)], {x, 0, 6}], lbl], 
  Column[{Style[lbl, Bold, Large], Control[{a, 0, 2}]}]]]
```

[image]

Is there a way to scope the `lbl` variable so that it is updated properly in the display?

Comment: you can simply wrap the `Style` with `Dynamic`. Note that you will always get 0 anyway, because that is the correct value following the substitution `x -> 0`

Comment: if $x=0$ you have $\sin(0\times( 1+a \times 0)) = \sin(0) =0$. Anyway, doesn't `Dynamic` solve your problem?

Comment: @dionys Maybe there's a typo? I get `0.` under the plot: http://i.stack.imgur.com/b5Jhw.png -- but it does seem to be a fairly irrelevant side-issue compared to getting `lbl` to display.

Comment: @glS Apologies. Yes, with a fresh kernel the original label would always be zero. I was just trying to throw an example together quickly and didn't notice that Global`x was leaking in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a variation that has the label above (in the control area) and below (in the plotlabel area). The trick is to have the Dynamic wrap around each of the instances of the `lbl` variable.

```
Manipulate[lbl = ToString[Sin[x (1 + a x)] /. x -> 1];
 Labeled[Plot[Sin[x (1 + a x)], {x, 0, 6}], Dynamic[lbl]], 
 Column[{Style[Dynamic[lbl], Bold, Large], Control[{a, 0, 2}]}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Why do you not like

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[Sin[x (1 + a x)], {x, 0, 6}, 
  PlotLabel -> Style[Sin[x (1 + a x)], Bold, FontSize -> 18]], {a, 0, 
  2}]
```

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is also useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: The example is a simplified demonstration. I don't care specifically about this plot. What I would like to do is dynamically update the label (or include more complicated updating) in the controls.

Comment: I must be missing something. The code above updates the label as you move the slider. What more do you seek?

Comment: @NicholasG The key here is "in the control area" ... it entails a different evaluation track because of how this part is executed inside of `Manipulate`.